# Can't cast database type timestamp without time zone to Instant

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, nodatime

```
reservationLogs = await this.dbContext.ReservationLogs
                   .Where(r => r.ProcessedAt == null)
                   .Where(r => r.PropertyId == validPropertyId)
                   .OrderBy(r => r.CreatedAt).ThenBy(r => r.Operation)
                   .Take(200)
                   .ToListAsync();
```

some times with the same query i get the error

> ' Can't cast database type timestamp without time zone to Instant'

note: CreatedAt nodaTime instane

i am trying to find the exact reason

Comment: Which database are you using? That database's ADO.NET and EF Core provider almost certainly know nothing about NodaTime, unless you install *something* (library or type converters) that tells them how to deal with it, like `EFCore.SqlServer.NodaTime`. There's no `timestamp without time zone` in SQL Server, which means you need to find a different library for your library

Comment: `tiemstamp without time zone` is a Postgresql type. Have you added the [NpgSQL NodaTime type plugin](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that even though the date and time is clear, it is unclear whether or which timezone was in use. If I tell you that tomorrow at 5 P.M. I will go for a walk, then it will be unclear from your perspective what the exact time it will be, unless you know what timezone was I assuming while saying so.

You have the exact same type of confusion in your code and first, you need to install this plugin: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html

According to the docs, you need to add a dependency like this:

```
using Npgsql;

// Place this at the beginning of your program to use NodaTime everywhere (recommended)
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseNodaTime();

// Or to temporarily use NodaTime on a single connection only:
conn.TypeMapper.UseNodaTime();
```

The docs go further in specifying how you can read and write values:

```
// Write NodaTime Instant to PostgreSQL "timestamp with time zone" (UTC)
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO mytable (my_timestamptz) VALUES (@p)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p", Instant.FromUtc(2011, 1, 1, 10, 30)));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

// Read timestamp back from the database as an Instant
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"SELECT my_timestamptz FROM mytable", conn))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    reader.Read();
    var instant = reader.GetFieldValue<Instant>(0);
}
```

Since you are not directly writing the query, but use the Entity Framework to do so you have another level of expression. But this is well-documented as well. You can safely and soundly declare types like this:

```
public LocalDate Date {get; set;}
```

Read this full article: https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2019/03/26/using-noda-time-with-ef-core.aspx

You will need to find out exactly where the error occurs. It seems to me that the `OrderBy` is the culprit as well as the selection. You can change the type of the data member of your model.

Comment: am using this on connection level as well

 conn.TypeMapper.UseNodaTime();

Answer (score 0):

You can do cast using [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime) package

> ```
> protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
> {
>     builder.UseNpgsql("connection-string",
>         o => o.UseNodaTime());
> }
> ```

or:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options => options.UseNpgsql(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConection"),
        o => o.UseNodaTime()));
```

[source](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html)